# use bib2gls in individually compiled subfiles

Tags: glossaries, subfiles, bib2gls

I am trying to use the `glossaries-extra` package with `record` (using `bib2gls`) option for a symbols list in a long document where each chapter can be compiled individually using the `subfiles` package.

My folder looks like this :

- main.tex
- symbols.bib
- sections :

  - chapter1.tex

and here is my MWE :

- `main` document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={symbols}]

\begin{document}
    \section{Main document}

    Here is some main text. I can reference \gls{test}.

    \subfile{./sections/chap1.tex}
\end{document}
```

- `symbols.bib` example :

```
@symbol{test,
    name = {test},
    description = {symbol description}
}
```

- `chapter1` subfile :

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

I want to reference \gls{test}, it will print fine in main file but I will only get ?? in subfile when compiled individually.
\end{document}
```

The recipe to compile the main file is, after every file has been saved to do :

```bash
pdflatex main
bib2gls main
pdflatex main
```

and here both references are printed correctly which makes sense because the main will include the subfiles and knows where the `.bib` is, but when I do :

```bash
cd sections/
pdflatex chapter1
bib2gls chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
```

I get an error saying that it can't find the `.bib`, and the pdf will print ?? instead of the symbol.

My question is : **is there a way to specify the `.bib` access path in each subfile ?**

This way i would produce a `chapter1.glstex` in the sections/ folder and I guess it would reference the symbols correctly.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please include some sample `symbols.bib` file? The preamble of your main document specifies it (`\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={symbols}]`), but since it is missing, `bib2gls` gives the `Error: symbols.bib (No such file or directory)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I modified my question to include the `.bib` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of the subfiles package, section 3.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf):

> 3.2 Fixing Pathes
>
> Whenever an error message of LaTeX or an external program indicates that a file cannot be found, the reason may be that the missing file has to be addressed by varying pathes, depending on which file is typeset. In such a case, it may help to apply the command `\subfix` to the file or path names. Examples: [...]

In your case, `bib2glg` complains about not finding `symbols.bib` when processing `chap1`. To fix it, use

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={\subfix{symbols}}]
```

in `main.tex`; note the added `\subfix`.